# Give "device administrator" permission to Android app that don't request

Tags: android, apk, device-admin

How to make any Android app require Device administrator permission?

Reason: I want to give WhatsApp "Device admin" permission; So that my organization that manages the device cannot delete it.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible.

A device administrator app need to implement an [DeviceAdminReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DeviceAdminReceiver) with a specific Manifest and declare admin policies on a specific xml file.

In other words, only an app designed to be device admin can have device admin permission. Which is not the case of WhatsApp.

Comment: Absolutely right.  As an aside-  the idea of giving a facebook app that kind of power over a device gives me chills as a user, and would absolutely violate the use policies of whoever administers the device.